# python-sphinx extension, extra html files

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am working on extension for sphinx doc generator.

I would like to add some html, js, css and json files to html build of the doc.

They are not part of template and they should not be affected by anything in sphinx template. They are just viewer for files which I would like to add in downloads folder. (I also do not how.)

How to include extra html files in sphinx extension?
JS/CSS can be added as described there https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/adding-custom-css.html but there is not a function for html.

```python
def setup(app):
    app.add_stylesheet('css/custom.css')
    app.add_javascript("js/custom.js")
    # and custom html or any generic file ?
```

Comment: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#jinja-sphinx-templating-primer  Do you have a `_templates` dir?

Comment: "(I also do not how.)" Do you mean you do not *know* how to copy files from the source to the build directory, and that is in fact your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a html_static_path in conf.py (it is list of paths). There you can add you static files (by folder).

In order to dynamically generate static files.
There is not a explicit way function to add static files. Instead static files can be just copied by python to html_static_path.

Where to find html_static_path?

```
class Node(nodes.TextElement):
    @staticmethod
    def visit_html(self, node), 
        self.document.settings.env.config.html_static_path

class Direc(Directive):
    def run(self):
        self.state.document.settings.env.config.html_static_path
```

Also html_static_path is relative to

`self.document.settings.env.app.confdir`

And build dir can be obrained by

`document.settings.env.app.builder.outdir`

There is more of html related config in http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html